MPLAB XC8 does not generate .HEX file after succesfully building .c file
As in title. I'm trying to program a PIC12F1840 microchip to blink a LED with the following code:
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 32000000 //define crystal frequency to 32MHz

void main(){
   TRISA = 0xEF; // Set RA4 pin as output

   // Loop to flash an LED on RA4 (pin 3)
   while(1){
      RA4 = 1; // Set RA4 high
      // Insert some delay
      int i = 1000;
      while(i--);

      RA4 = 0; // Set RA4 low
      // Insert some delay
      i = 1000;
      while(i--);
   }

   return;
}

The build is succesful with the following output:
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/debug/prova.X.debug.elf
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/jacopo/MPLABXProjects/prova.X'
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.46\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=12F1840 -c  -D__DEBUG=1  -mdebugger=none   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.20/packs/Microchip/PIC12-16F1xxx_DFP/1.7.242/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx32 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall -mno-default-config-bits   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/debug/main.p1 main.c 
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/jacopo/MPLABXProjects/prova.X'
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/jacopo/MPLABXProjects/prova.X'
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.46\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=12F1840 -Wl,-Map=dist/default/debug/prova.X.debug.map  -D__DEBUG=1  -mdebugger=none  -DXPRJ_default=default  -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.20/packs/Microchip/PIC12-16F1xxx_DFP/1.7.242/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx32 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall -mno-default-config-bits -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto         -Wl,--memorysummary,dist/default/debug/memoryfile.xml -o dist/default/debug/prova.X.debug.elf  build/default/debug/main.p1     

Memory Summary:
    Program space        used    31h (    49) of  1000h words   (  1.2%)
    Data space           used     4h (     4) of   100h bytes   (  1.6%)
    EEPROM space         used     0h (     0) of   100h bytes   (  0.0%)
    Configuration bits   used     0h (     0) of     2h words   (  0.0%)
    ID Location space    used     0h (     0) of     4h bytes   (  0.0%)

make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/jacopo/MPLABXProjects/prova.X'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7s)
Loading symbols from C:/Users/jacopo/MPLABXProjects/prova.X/dist/default/debug/prova.X.debug.elf...
Loading code from C:/Users/jacopo/MPLABXProjects/prova.X/dist/default/debug/prova.X.debug.elf...
Program loaded with pack,PIC12-16F1xxx_DFP,1.7.242,Microchip
Loading completed

I looked in other forums but I wasn't able to resolve the issue. Thank you beforehand for your help.

Looks like you're doing a debug build. Try a release build...

From what I can see, recent versions of the MPLAB X IDE changed the Build/ Clean and Build buttons so that Debug builds are default (instead of production). I need to remind myself of it still. Or train myself to use the F11/ Shift+F11 hot keys.
